# Подсчёт динамики и отрицательные индексы массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Рассматривал материал по скобочным последовательностям и наткнулся на такую динамику:

> Научимся считать вспомогательную динамику `d[i][j]`, где `i` — длина
>   скобочной последовательности (она "полуправильная": всякой закрывающей
>   скобке соответствует парная открывающая, но не все открытые скобки
>   закрыты), `j` — баланс (т.е. разность между количеством открывающих и
>   закрывающих скобок), `d[i][j]` — количество таких последовательностей.
>   При подсчёте этой динамики мы считаем, что скобки бывают только одного
>   типа.
>
> Считать эту динамику можно следующим образом.
>
> Пусть `d[i][j]` — величина, которую мы хотим посчитать. Если `i = 0`,
>   то ответ понятен сразу: `d[0][0] = 1`, все остальные `d[0][j] = 0`.
>   Пусть теперь `i > 0`, тогда переберём, чему мог быть равен последний
>   символ этой последовательности. Если он был равен '(', то до этого
>   символа мы находились в состоянии `(i-1,j-1)`. Если он был равен ')',
>   то предыдущим было состояние `(i-1,j+1)`. Таким образом, получаем
>   формулу: `d[i][j] = d[i-1][j-1] + d[i-1][j+1]` ***(считается, что все
>   значения `d[i][j]` при отрицательном `j` равны нулю)***.
>
> Таким образом, эту динамику мы можем посчитать за O(n^2).

[Источник](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)
Как подсчитать такую динамику? И самое главное, как обращаться к отрицательным индексам массива?

Моё решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int d[s.size()][s.size()];
    d[0][0] = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i <= s.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= s.size(); ++j)
        {
            int a, b;
            if(i == 0)
            {
                if(j == 0)
                    d[i][j] = 1;
                else
                    d[i][j] = 0;
            }
            if(j < 0)
                d[i][j] = 0;
            if(i > 0)
            {
                if(s[i] == '(')
                    d[i][j] = d[i - 1][j - 1];
                if(s[i] == ')')
                    d[i][j] = d[i - 1][j + 1];
                if(s[i] == '?')
                    d[i][j] = d[i - 1][j - 1] + d[i - 1][j + 1];;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= s.size(); ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j <= s.size(); ++j)
            cout << d[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: под динамикой там понимается - динамическое программирование, которое используется для  сохранение результатов выполнения функций для предотвращения повторных вычислений (мемоизации).

Comment: индексы в массиве не могут быть отрицательными

Comment: Где вы в описании алгоритма увидели необходимость *обращаться* к отрицательным индексам массива? Выделенная жирным фраза как раз таки говорит вам, что обращаться к массиву не надо, а надо сразу полагать (*не обращаясь к массиву*), что для отрицательных `j` значения `d[i][j]` равны нулю.

Comment: @LexHobbit Можете можете указать на ошибку в программе? Добавил свой код в вопросе

Comment: @AndreyVarfolomeev, при отрицательных `j` не нужно ни писать, ни читать в массив с такими индексами. Нужна отдельная переменная, куда читается значение из массива. Если значение `j` отрицательно, то сразу записать туда 0. Если неотрицательно - то записать туда значение из массива.